# Problem finding correct Selector for response.xpath or response.css in Scrapy on Coinmarketcap

Tags: xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

i´d like to loop over the top20 exchanges on coinmarketcap to crawl the tables, e.g. https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/fatbtc/

Now i spent a few hours in finding the Selector, e.g. for *Price*

In Scrapy Shell i tried ... and many more, but all not working:

from Addon *XPath Helper*:

```
response.xpath('/html/body/div[@id='__next']/div[@class='cmc-app-wrapper.cmc-app-wrapper--env-prod.sc-1mezg3x-0.fUoBLh']/div[@class='container.cmc-main-section']/div[@class='cmc-main-section__content']/div[@class='cmc-exchanges.sc-1tluhf0-0.wNRWa']/div[@class='cmc-details-panel-table.sc-3klef5-0.cSzKTI']/div[@class='cmc-markets-listing.lgsxp9-0.eCrwnv']/div[@class='cmc-table.sc-1yv6u5n-0.dNLqEp']/div[@class='cmc-table__table-wrapper-outer']/div/table/tbody/tr[@class='cmc-table-row.sc-1ebpa92-0.kQmhAn'][1]/td[@class='cmc-table__cell.cmc-table__cell--sortable.cmc-table__cell--right.cmc-table__cell--sort-by__price']').getall()
```

from Chrome Inspector:

```
response.xpath('/td[@class='cmc-table__cell.cmc-table__cell--sortable.cmc-table__cell--right.cmc-table__cell--sort-by__price']').getall()
```

from Chrome Inspector *copy XPath*:
:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]').extract()
```

I´m using the Chrome Inspector and since today an addon called "Xpath helper" for showing the Selectors, but i still don´t really understand what i´m doing there :(. I´d really appreciate any idea how to access that data and to give me a better understanding in finding these selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy (I used `position()` to skip table header):

```
for row in response.xpath('//table[@id="exchange-markets"]//tr[position() > 1]'):
    price = row.xpath('.//span[@class="price"]/text()').get()
#    price = row.xpath('.//span[@class="price"]/@data-usd').get() #if you need to be more precise
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It´s working. Don´t know why, but my Chrome Dev Inspector does not show me id. Strange! Startet Edge and there it was...

Answer (score 0):

XPATHs are basically //tagname[@attribute='value'] from HTML.

For your site, you can loop over names with `//table[@id='exchange-markets']//tr/td[2]/a`

and get prices with `//table[@id='exchange-markets']//tr/td[5]`

where we are basically saying to look within the table rows on column 5.